# Efficiency of returning a dataframe vs writing to and reading a csv from disk

Tags: python-3.x, function, pandas, dataframe

I have a very modular codebase with a number of functions. Some of these functions produce pretty big dataframes, which I am saving to the disk using to_csv(), and then directly returning the dataframe to the calling function.

**EDITING** to explain the problem better, using example functions from @ysearka's answer

This is what I am currently doing:

```
def my_func(some_input):
    #df = something(some_input)
    return dataframe

df = my_func(my_input)
```

Another approach I think is to read the file from the disk in the calling function after the write has been completed:

```
def my_func(some_input):
    #df = something(some_input)
    df.to_csv('my_file_name.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('my_file_name.csv')
```

My question is: Which of the above is the more effective way of achieving this?

- Returning the dataframe to the calling function?
- Reading the file from the disk in the calling function after the write has been completed.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? A little context would help.

Comment: I edited my answer, but as we don't know what you're trying to do afterwards with your dataframe, I can't do much better.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

The answer to this question is a bit tricky as it depends on what you're trying to achieve afterwards.

Indeed if you then need to load your entire dataframe in RAM (as you do when creating or reading a dataframe with Pandas), then you probably don't want to go through `to_csv read_csv` as it will have to go through your disk twice. This will take time to write and as much time to read (not counting if you have things to parse like dates, etc...).

The advantage of this method though, would be to have a save of your files. So that if you screw your dataframe afterwards, you just have to load them back with `read_csv` instead of re-creating them. Also, if you don't need the full dataframe to work on, you can just load the desired chunk of your file using `pandas.read_csv(skiprows = 10, nrows = 100)`. This will help not to overload your RAM.

If you don't need these techniques, I recommend you to just return the dataframe from the function without writing it on your disk. It will be way faster.

To complete this answer, I would recommend using `to_pickle` and `read_pickle` as it's way faster than `to_csv` and `read_csv` when you're only using your files with pandas.